# SQL - Modify field only if all records with same id meet a requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm fairly new to SQL and have a question about an UPDATE query. I'm using SQL server 2008 R2. I have written the following SELECT query:

```
SELECT res.labresultcat_id, res.patient_id, lab.test_performed,
       lab.result_status, lab.result_value, lab.abnormal_flag, res.recorded_on, 
       res.cat_test_name, res.results_to, usr.last_name, res.result_viewed
FROM dbo.med_labresultcat res
  INNER JOIN dbo.med_labresult lab
    ON res.labresultcat_id = lab.labresultcat_id
  LEFT JOIN dbo.res_user usr
    ON res.results_to = usr.resource_id
WHERE lab.result_status = 'F' AND usr.last_name = 'Smith'
  AND res.result_viewed is NULL
```

The results of which look something like this:

```
patient_id    result_id   test_performed     abnormal_flag    recorded_on    results_to    
0001          0045        ABC                N                4/1/2013       14            
0001          0045        CBS                A                4/1/2013       14           
0002          0061        NBC                N                4/3/2013       13            
0002          0061        MST                N                4/3/2013       13
0003          0090        ABC                H                4/20/2013      10
0003          0090        MST                N                4/20/2013      10
```

What I'm trying to do is UPDATE the results_to field only when all the records with the  same result_id are = N or NULL

So, I've written the following UPDATE query:

```
;WITH lab AS
  (
   select RES.labresultcat_id, res.cat_test_name, res.results_to, 
          res.result_status,
          lab.test_performed, lab.result_value, lab.abnormal_flag, 
          res.result_viewed, usr.last_name
   from DBO.med_labresultcat RES 
     INNER JOIN dbo.med_labresult lab
       ON res.labresultcat_id = lab.labresultcat_id
     LEFT JOIN DBO.res_user USR
       ON res.results_to = usr.resource_id
   WHERE res.result_viewed is null AND lab.result_status = 'F'
     and RES.test_date <= '03/15/2013' AND usr.last_name = 'Smith'
   )
   UPDATE lab SET results_to = CASE WHEN 0 = (SELECT COUNT(abnormal_flag)
   WHERE abnormal_flag = 'A' OR abnormal_flag = 'H' OR abnormal_flag = 'L')
   THEN '146' ELSE results_to END
```

However, the above query throws the SQL error "An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an update statement" Unfortunately, the research for this error goes above my understanding of SQL.

I would really appreciate if someone could provide some clear direction of how to move forward on this as I'm very stuck right now.

Comment: Just a minor "heads up" comment... when you `LEFT JOIN` to a table and then add logic to limit the dataset based upon a field in that table in the `WHERE` criteria you effectively turn the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
 ;WITH lab AS
 (
  select RES.labresultcat_id, res.cat_test_name, res.results_to, 
         res.result_status,
         lab.test_performed, lab.result_value, lab.abnormal_flag, 
         res.result_viewed, usr.last_name
  from DBO.med_labresultcat RES
    INNER JOIN dbo.med_labresult lab ON res.labresultcat_id = lab.labresultcat_id
    LEFT JOIN DBO.res_user USR ON res.results_to = usr.resource_id
  WHERE res.result_viewed is null AND lab.result_status = 'F' 
    and RES.test_date <= '03/15/2013' AND usr.last_name = 'Smith'
  )
  UPDATE l
  SET l.results_to = '146'
  FROM lab l
  WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM lab l2
                WHERE l.result_id = l2.result_id                  
                HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ISNULL(l2.abnormal_flag, 'N')) = 1
                ) AND ISNULL(l.abnormal_flag, 'N') = 'N'
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/326d6/3)

Comment: Thank you very much for responding to my question. I've used the query above and it does run. However, for example I have two results with the same result_id, one has an abnormal_flag of 'N' the other has an abnormal_flag of 'A' - using the above query, it gets reassigned...but since one of the results has an abnormal_flag of 'A' it shouldn't be reassigned.

Comment: Note the result_id = 93 in example on SQLFiddle have two results with the same result_id, one has an abnormal_flag of 'N' the other has an abnormal_flag of 'A' - using the above query, it not reassigned.

Comment: You're absolutely right Alex. the actual column name is slightly different then what I posted here, so once I put in the correct column name the query worked perfectly.

You're awesome. Thanks again!